Can't create stripped GeoTIFF with GDAL
I need my GeoTIFFs to be stripped rather than tiled and in Float32 format. I would normally run:
gdal_translate -ot Float32 INPUT.tif OUTPUT.tif

to do this as gdal_translate creates stripped outputs by default. But on this one file, it always creates a Nx2 block size instead of Nx1. Nothing I do to this file forces it to be stripped!
Here's the info for the input file:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: .\MedianStandardError.tif
       .\MedianStandardError.tif.ovr
       .\MedianStandardError.tif.aux.xml
Size is 977, 605
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-134.299975884162251,55.091554318092584)
Pixel Size = (0.012052407420278,-0.012052407420278)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-134.2999759,  55.0915543) (134d17'59.91"W, 55d 5'29.60"N)
Lower Left  (-134.2999759,  47.7998478) (134d17'59.91"W, 47d47'59.45"N)
Upper Right (-122.5247738,  55.0915543) (122d31'29.19"W, 55d 5'29.60"N)
Lower Right (-122.5247738,  47.7998478) (122d31'29.19"W, 47d47'59.45"N)
Center      (-128.4123749,  51.4457011) (128d24'44.55"W, 51d26'44.52"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = SE_median
  Min=0.679 Max=5.053
  Minimum=0.679, Maximum=5.053, Mean=1.282, StdDev=0.409
  NoData Value=nan
  Overviews: 489x303, 245x152
  Metadata:
    BandName=SE_median
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=0.1668946746774383
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5.0525321960449
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1.2818055667176
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=nan
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0.67931514978409
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.40852744666355

and here's the output file after running gdal_translate:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: .\MedianStandardError_ShouldBeStripped.tif
Size is 977, 605
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-134.299975884162251,55.091554318092584)
Pixel Size = (0.012052407420278,-0.012052407420278)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-134.2999759,  55.0915543) (134d17'59.91"W, 55d 5'29.60"N)
Lower Left  (-134.2999759,  47.7998478) (134d17'59.91"W, 47d47'59.45"N)
Upper Right (-122.5247738,  55.0915543) (122d31'29.19"W, 55d 5'29.60"N)
Lower Right (-122.5247738,  47.7998478) (122d31'29.19"W, 47d47'59.45"N)
Center      (-128.4123749,  51.4457011) (128d24'44.55"W, 51d26'44.52"N)
Band 1 Block=977x2 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = SE_median
  Min=0.679 Max=5.053
  Minimum=0.679, Maximum=5.053, Mean=1.282, StdDev=0.409
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    BandName=SE_median
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=0.1668946746774383
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5.0525321960449
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1.2818055667176
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=nan
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0.67931514978409
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.40852744666355


From the GDAL dataset driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html perhaps if you used the confirguation option -co TILED=NO it might force striped instead of a block N x 2 size.

Ya @MichaelStimson it was the BLOCKYSIZE option described below that did the trick but I'm also setting TILED=NO just to be safe.

What you have is a stripped TIFF, having 2-row strips. An excerpt from the TIFF specification:

Compressed or uncompressed image data can be stored almost anywhere in
a TIFF file. TIFF also supports breaking an image into separate strips
for increased editing flexibility and efficient I/O buffering. The
location and size of each strip is given by the following fields:
RowsPerStrip Tag = 278 (116.H) Type = SHORT or LONG The number of rows
in each strip (except possibly the last strip.) For example, if
ImageLength is 24, and RowsPerStrip is 10, then there are 3 strips,
with 10 rows in the first strip, 10 rows in the second strip, and 4
rows in the third strip. (The data in the last strip is not padded
with 6 extra rows of dummy data.)

For creating 1-row strips use GDAL creation option BLOCKYSIZE=1 https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options

BLOCKYSIZE=: Set tile or strip height. Tile height defaults
to 256, strip height defaults to a value such that one strip is 8K or
less. Must be divisible by 16 when TILED=YES.

Your image is small and obviously two pixels rows fit into 8K. Therefore GDAL gives you 2-row strips with the default settings.
